.NET 8 Maui app ICommand RelayCommand not working
I've stripped almost everything, except the pertinent info.  BaseViewModel inherits from ObservableObject.
I started with a traditional WPF MVVM approach but could no longer make ICommands work. Although it does seem to work fine in a Maui Blazor Hybrid app but this is just a Maui App.
From what I found RelayCommand is the correct approach with the latest Maui but my Button Command won't work, no matter what I've tried.  Any suggestions?
SignInViewModel.cs:
public partial class SignInViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand UserLoginCommand { get; set; }

    public SignInViewModel()
    {
        UserLoginCommand = new RelayCommand(UserLogin);
    }

    async void UserLogin()
    {
       ...
    }
}

XAML markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NMMaui"
    x:Class="NMMaui.Views.SignInPage"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NMMaui.ViewModels"
    Title="Sign In"
    HeightRequest="600"
    Background="Silver">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:SignInViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
            <Button 
            Grid.Row="10" 
            Text="Sign In" 
            FontAttributes="Bold" 
            TextColor="White" 
            Margin="0,20" 
            HeightRequest="50" 
            CornerRadius="10"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Command="{Binding UserLoginCommand}"
            BackgroundColor="#508390">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>


is UserLoginCommand a public property?

Yes. Screwed up the formatting a bit.
public RelayCommand UserLoginCommand { get; set; }

public partial class SignInViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //public RelayCommand UserLoginCommand { get; set; }

    public SignInViewModel()
    {
        //UserLoginCommand = new RelayCommand(UserLogin);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task UserLoginAsync()
    {
        ...
    }  
}



Gave this a try but no luck.  Maybe something with the Button control itself?

No, the button looks fine, I will try it

It works, see the results

Thank you for your help, I have no idea what's going on with my configuration, it just won't work

Spoke too soon, got it working.   Strange error.   Looks like I mistakenly specified the Grid.Row of the button outside the bounds of the containing grids rows.  Not sure why it's even displaying.  Once I changed the row number to a correct value, it works!  Thanks again for your help.

You're welcome, Glad it works! Strange error That's the nature of programming، spending days on a simple mistake
